# MVVM Light Hub Control SectionsInViewChanged RelayCommand

Tags: events, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

Is it possible to bind a MVVM Light, Relay Command to the **SectionsInViewChanged** Event in a Hub Control?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used the new Hub control, but it should be like others.  You may bind RelayCommands to events using EventToCommand.  Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx .

Snippet that shows the Loaded event of this user control bound firing the LoadedCommand:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Bill.Views.Setup.AdjustmentReasonsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
         xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF45"
         xmlns:igDP="http://infragistics.com/DataPresenter"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         >

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=LoadedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

.
.
.